# Is it true that particles on the liquid surface are having high kinetic energy?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics

I read that in case of liquid the particle in the bulk experiences a negative potential energy due to the force of attraction around it. Particles on the surface, however  experiences less potential energy. That is they must have more kinetic energy causing them to move. Is my assessment correct? If I'm right, why does a liquid **require more energy** to spread out and which energy are they referring to

Answer (score 1):

The molecules in the surface of a liquid only have bonds with their neighbours below the surface whereas molecules in the bulk make bonds all around them.

Thus the binding energy of molecules in the surface is less than those in the bulk and so the potential energy of molecules in the surface is greater than those in the bulk.

As the liquid wants to minimise its potential energy it will try and reduce the number of surface molecules by reducing the area its surface area and thus reducing what you have called surface potential energy.

The (thermal) kinetic energy is due to the random movement and vibrations of liquid molecules and at equilibrium the average kinetic energy of all the molecules is the same - they are all at the same temperature.

Comment: It is probably not true that the bonds are longer at the surface. Fewer bonds means less steric hindrance, so if there is a difference, those bonds are likely to be shorter.

Comment: @Pieter I have removed the comment about the bond length although I must confess I am not sure what steric hindrance has to do with the separation of molecules being greater at the surface?  Looking at your profile I am sure you can tell me?

Comment: Your post still says that the separation of the molecules is larger at the surface.  I rather doubt that. Might be true in some kinds of liquids, but my gut feeling is that it is the other way around in most. When the atoms are not as much in the way for each other, and when the bond valence sum is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Classically, [equipartition of energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/eqpar.html) applies: kinetic energy only depends on temperature so it is the same in the liquid and in the gas at equilibrium. And at the surface of the liquid. (In quantum mechanics, this is not true; zero-point motion of hydrogen atoms is important in water at room temperature, but no need to get into such complications now.)

Comment: I din't get you.

Comment: I tried to give an answer to the question in the header. I do not quite understand the rest of the question. What do you mean by spreading out? who are "they"?

Comment: I meant what if we increase the surface area of the liquid , according to my textbook (that's what I meant by 'they') if we increase the surface area of a liquid it's surface energy increases, I am assuming it's because of an increase in kinetic energy of the particles.

Comment: @susanJ There is maybe a problem with the sign? This seems to be about stretching a thin film. If stretching is done adiabatically (without heat exchange with the environment), I would expect the temperature and the kinetic energy to go down. I do not know if this is possible to measure, but one might try with a thermal camera.